# Use WCF Service or ASP.NET Web api for biometric device?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a web application(HRMS) in asp.net MVC4 and a Windows Form (later on converted in windows service) connected to a biometric device. So question is should I use WCF Service or asp.net web api to send attendance data?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go for ASP.NET Web API.**

> Use WCF to create reliable, secure web services that accessible over a
>   variety of transports. Use ASP.NET Web API to create HTTP-based
>   services that are accessible from a wide variety of clients. Use
>   ASP.NET Web API if you are creating and designing new REST-style
>   services. Although WCF provides some support for writing REST-style
>   services, the support for REST in ASP.NET Web API is more complete and
>   **all future REST feature improvements will be made in ASP.NET Web API**. If you have an existing WCF service and you want to expose
>   additional REST endpoints, use WCF and the WebHttpBinding.

Its better to stay with WebAPI as it looks to be more appropriate for building further real RESTfull service development. WCF was originally created to enable SOAP-based services. For simpler RESTful or RPCish services (think clients like jQuery) **ASP.NET Web API should be good choice**.

Comment: thanks for your response. I have three values in my attendance data i.e employee id, date and time. so should i use post method or get method by passing values in parameters

Comment: Essentially GET is used to retrieve remote data, and POST is used to insert/update remote data. So it depends on what kind of operation (retrieve, insert or update) are you doing.

Comment: Dont forget to upvote if you satisfied with my answer.

Comment: I m inserting data from windows form via web service. So I have to use post which requires me to add same type (attendance class with properties) on both side i.e web api where insert logic is written and on windows service where i m consuming the service. am I right?

Comment: Ya, in this case you can use POST.